# AdS compactification of Minkowski space

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I am trying to understand the paper "Anti De Sitter Space And Holography" by E. Witten (cf. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9802150).
One of the first point it makes is that "Minkowski space appears as the boundary of AdS space" as a compactification.
In order to accomplish this he presents the relation
$$uv-\sum_{i,j} \eta_{ij}x^i x^j=0\tag{1.1}$$
subject to the scaling $u\rightarrow su,v\rightarrow sv, x^i\rightarrow sx^i$,
where $\eta_{ij}$ is the Lorentz metric of signature $-++...+$.
This equation defines a manifold such that
$$
-dudv + \sum_{i,j} \eta_{ij} dx^i dx^j \tag{p.3}
$$
is preserved under the action of $SO(2,d)$.
He then claims that since, in general, $v\neq 0$ we can set $v=1$ "after which one uses the equation to solve for $u$".

- I fail to see how Minkowski space arises at the boundary. Can anyone provide some information or the intermediate steps of Witten's proof?
- Why is the metric tensor for AdS in that form? It does not look like the usual expressions for AdS with that mixed term $dudv$.

I tried to use the information in one of the comments in [Conformal compatification of Minkowski and AdS](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/conformal-compatification-of-minkowski-and-ads) to do my own proof:
Solving eq. 1 for $u$ and taking the differential yields
$$
du= \frac{1}{v}\eta_{ij}dx^i x^j+ \frac{1}{v} \eta_{ij} x^i dx^j - \frac{1}{v^2}\eta_{ij}x^i x^j dv
$$
If the metric is given by
$$
ds^2 = dudv - \eta_{ij}dx^i dx^j
$$
then it follows that
$$
\lim_{v\rightarrow \infty} ds^2 = -\eta_{ij}dx^i dx^j
$$
We can now see the Minkoski metric arising at infinity and a pole for $v=0$, as expected.
This leads me to another few questions:

- What is the meaning of the minus sign in front of $\eta_{ij}$ after taking the limit $v\rightarrow \infty$? Why should it be there?
- Since the reasoning can be applied *mutatis mutandis* to $u$, does it mean at the boundary in $u \rightarrow \infty$ we also find Minkowski space at the boundary and a pole at $u=0$?

Comment: The missing metric tensor on p.3 is a typo.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have edited the question since that is now clear.